# C# Threading arguments are invalid

Tags: c#

i got this Code from an Old post

```
public delegate void Worker();
private static Thread worker;

public static void Init(Worker work)
{
    worker = new Thread(new ThreadStart(work));
    worker.Start();
}

public static void Work()
{
    string result = testing;
}
```

I modify the code by adding parameters , when i try to call Init("AA") I am getting an error "Best overload method has some invalid arguments"

The following is the edited code

```
    public delegate void Worker();
private static Thread worker;

public static void Init(Worker work)
{
    worker = new Thread(new ThreadStart(work));
    worker.Start();
}

public static void Work(string testing)
{
    string result = testing;
}
```

Comment: And what is it you are trying to do here?

Answer (score 2):

Your `Init` method takes a delegate and you are passing a string, that is why there is no overload.

you want to do : `Init(Work)`

PS : your issue has nothing to do with threading.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass some data to thread you can use [ParametrizedThreadStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx), or anonymous method:

```
private static Thread worker;

public static void Init(string testing)
{
    // passing anonymous method, which will capture parameter
    worker = new Thread(() => Work(testing));
    worker.Start();
}

public static void Work(string testing)
{
    string result = testing;
}
```

---

```
private static Thread worker;

public static void Init(string testing)
{
    // passing PrametrizedThreadStart delegate
    worker = new Thread(Work);
    worker.Start(testing); // passing parameter
}

// PrametrizedThreadStart delegate accepts object as parameter
public static void Work(object testing)
{
    string result = (string)testing;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `Worker` delegate expect take a `string` parameter. You need to update that and *then* pass in the parameter e.g.

```
public delegate void Worker(string str);
private static Thread worker;
public static void Init(Worker work)
{
    worker = new Thread(work);
    worker.Start("AA");
}
public static void Work(string testing)
{
    string result = testing;
}
```